# Concatenating three lists into one with LINQ throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Ok, I must be doing something dumb, but shouldn't this work?  I have following three lists:

```
var commonViews = (from v in context.TPM_VIEWS where v.VIEWID < 0 select v); // IQueryable<TPM_VIEWS>
var ownedViews = (from v in context.TPM_VIEWS where v.OWNERID == userId && v.VIEWID > 0 select v); // IQueryable<TPM_VIEWS>
var sharedViews = (from v in context.TPM_USER.Include("TPM_VIEWS2") where v.USERID == userId select v).First().TPM_VIEWS2; // EntityCollection<TPM_VIEWS>
```

Each list has the proper values and count.  I can return any one of these lists:

```
return commonViews.ToList();
```

And I can return a any *two* of these lists:

```
return commonViews.Concat(ownedViews).ToList();
```

However, when I try to return all three:

```
return commonViews.Concat(ownedViews).Concat(sharedViews).ToList();
```

I get the exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entity.TPM_VIEWS'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What am I doing wrong?  All three values are indeed enumerable.  Mostly, I'm asking this question because it's the best possible way to guarantee I'll notice the problem 30 seconds after posting.

**UPDATE:**

I'm 93% sure the problem is here:

```
var sharedViews = (from v in context.TPM_USER.Include("TPM_VIEWS2") where v.USERID == userId select v).First().TPM_VIEWS2;
```

This *looks* like an enumerable list of `TPM_VIEWS` object, and I can call `ToList()` on it and get the correct data, but it doesn't play well with the other lists.

**UPDATE 2:**

This actually works.  Points to the person who can tell me why!

```
commonViews.ToList().Concat(ownedViews.ToList()).Concat(sharedViews.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Try putting `sharedViews` first.  Yes; I seriously suspect that will fix it.

Comment: based on my extremely basic history with EF, I'd be willing to bet a fiver @SLaks is right.

Comment: Ok yea this is weird.  `sharedViews.Concat(commonViews).Concat(ownedViews).Count()` returns 6 (which is correct), but `sharedViews.Concat(commonViews).Concat(ownedViews).ToList();` throws the same exception.  It's something funky with `sharedViews` for sure.  Basically, I need to get an `IEnumerable<TPM_VIEWS>` from the given `userId`.

Comment: @JerKimball - Putting $5 on SLaks is *usually* a safe bet, but I think there's something else screwy going on.

Comment: Can you call ToList() on each Enumerable and concatenate the lists properly?

Comment: @Kevin - Yup, if I add `.ToList()` to the end of each LINQ expression (thus materializing the query), I can aggregate.  This isn't a *bad* solution, but it still leaves me scratching my head a bit.  It must be something funky the Entity Framework is doing to try to materialize the entire expression tree at once.

Comment: Isnt the `ToList();` changing it from IQueryable to IEnumerable which is what is needed for the concat?

Comment: `ToList()` forces LINQ to immediately pull the data from the source and materialize it in memory.  Once in memory, you are using LINQ to Objects with three `List<TPM_VIEWS>` objects.

Comment: @James - Something like that, though I can `Concat()` `commonViews` and `ownedViews` - Perhaps because those can be combined into a single SQL statement?

Comment: One might try `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()`, which will force use of simple LINQ operators instead of generating a large EF IQueryable. Should have the same effect as `.ToList()` but be considerably more efficient regarding memory usage.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that EF can concatenate two queries and combine them into a single query that can be materialized at once, however if it's *unable* to combine them *before* they're materialized, it throws an error (and extremely unhelpful error mind you).  If any EF expert wants to formalize a good explanation, I'll Accept this.

Comment: @MikeChristensen you call `First` on `commonViews` and `ToList()` on `ownedViews`

Comment: @James - `commonViews` can have more than one item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Concat()` on an EF `IQueryable<T>` will turn the entire concatenation into a single query.

When you call `.Concat(sharedViews)`, you're passing a scalar (pre-loaded) collection of your nested entity class.
EF doesn't know how to convert that into a query, so it complains.

You can make it faster by calling `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`.

Comment: Excellent, I think this sums up everything nicely!

Comment: So does @MikeChristensen get $5 or not?

Answer (score 1):

> This actually works. Points to the person who can tell me why!
>
> ```
> commonViews.ToList().Concat(ownedViews.ToList()).Concat(sharedViews.ToList()).ToList();
> ```

That's because each of the original queries is executed separately; you're only concatenating the results in memory. There seems to be a bug in the Entity Framework query translator when you combine the 3 queries, but when you call `ToList` on each of them, they're no longer EF queries, they're just lists, so they're concatenated using Linq to Objects.